# marionette router does not work. Cannot navigate to a route from address bar

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, backbone-routing

I have a backbone marionette application with requirejs for loading module. Everything else is working just fine as expected. Until I put router in it. The router and controller binding does not seem to work. When I go to a route from address bar: in this case `homedomain#edit/id`, the router is rerouted to home page. I am taking reference of `Marionette a Gentle Introduction By David Sulc` for most of my code.

```
    'use strict';

    define([
        'app',
        'email_templates',
        'email_list_controller'
    ], function(App) {

        App.module('Email', function(Email, App, Backbone, Marionette) {
            Email.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
                appRoutes: {
                    'edit/:id' : 'editEmails',
                    '': 'listEmails'
                }
            });

            var API = {
                listEmails: function() {
                    require(['email_list_controller'], function(controller) {
                        App.navigate('/');
                        controller.list();
                    });
                },
                editEmails: function(item){
                    alert(item); //initial debugging point. this line is referenced in description below.
                    require(['email_edit_controller'], function(controller){
                        var id = typeof item === "string" ? item : item.id;
                        App.navigate('edit/'+id);
                        controller.editor(item);
                    });
                }
            };

            Email.on('start', function() {
                new Email.Router({
                    controller: API,
                });
            });
        });

        return App.Email;
    });
```

From my understanding so far when I navigate to a route: `#edit/<someRandomId>` the `<someRandomId>` should be alerted on the screen. The exact line has been referenced. This is just my approach to see if the router is working. But in fact the whole `Email.Router` is not working.

Comment: How are you starting Backbone's router? `Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true } )`? If so the `pushState = true` only recognizes full urls, not hashes.

Comment: @stakolee `Backbone.history.start()`on app start.